# IOS FirebaseUI sign in customization

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm trying to customize the FirebaseUI sign in - but there is no change.

I have an icon - sign in which the user will click the icon to get the sign in screen -

```
guard let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI() else { return }
            authUI.delegate = self
            let providers: [FUIAuthProvider] = [
                FUIGoogleAuth(),
                FUIEmailAuth(),
                FUIFacebookAuth()
            ]
            authUI.providers = providers
            authUI.tosurl = URL(string: "hi")
            authUI.privacyPolicyURL = URL(string: "pwned")
            let authViewController = authUI.authViewController()
            self.present(authViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Then, the instructions to customize the sign in is to create a custom viewcontroller in the delegate of FirebaseAuthDelegate -

```
func authPickerViewController(forAuthUI authUI: FUIAuth) -> FUIAuthPickerViewController {
        return AuthenicationViewController(authUI : authUI)
    }
```

Then I tried to change the color of background in the custom viewcontroller -

```
class AuthenicationViewController: FUIAuthPickerViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

    }
}
```

I tried adding an image as well but it doesn't work either. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom .xib with

```
    func authPickerViewController(forAuthUI authUI: FUIAuth) -> FUIAuthPickerViewController {
    return AuthenicationViewController(nibName: "YourCustomPickerXIB",
        bundle: Bundle.main,
        authUI: authUI)
}
```

You can customize using [sample on repo](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/blob/master/samples/swift/FirebaseUI-demo-swift/Samples/Auth/FUICustomAuthPickerViewController.xib)

PD: you have a typo on AuthenicationViewController missing t.